# What kind of power is referred to in "the...most powerful all-electric propulsion communications satellite ever produced"

Tags: spacex, communication-satellite, power, ses

The Florida Today article [On second flight, SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket to launch 'brute' of a satellite from Cape](https://www.floridatoday.com/story/tech/science/space/2018/05/30/spacex-falcon-9-launch-brute-satellite-cape-canaveral-florida-ses-12/655007002/) describes the upcoming SpaceX launch of SES-12. Next to this tiny image of (presumably) SES-12 is the caption:

[image]

> SES-12 is the largest and most powerful all-electric propulsion communications satellite ever produced, according to manufacturer Airbus Defense and Space. The satellite's launch from Cape Canaveral on a SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket is targeted for 12:29 a.m. Friday, June 1.

The main text of the article also says:

> According to Airbus, the satellite is the biggest and most powerful yet to rely entirely on electric propulsion to reach and hold its final orbit high over the equator.

**Question:** Are they talking about the power output of the solar array, or total RF power transmitted, or power used for the all-electric propulsion, or even the total thrust available ("powerful thrusters")?

Related (though not all-electric propulsion): [ViaSat's 18 kW solar array - largest ever for a commercial telecom satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21749/12102)

Comment: http://www.airbus.com/space/telecommunications-satellites/electric-propulsion-satellites.html

Comment: While it may be the most powerful all-electric-propulsion sat by solar array output or by transmission power, the text is almost certainly referring to power measured by marketing budget.

Comment: https://www.ses.com/newsroom/ses-12-elevating-experiences-today  " payload of 6 wide beams and 72 high throughput user spot beams". 72 is huge number..

Comment: I think the main rival is Vaisat-1 satellite (launched in 2011). It also have 72 Ka-band spot beams, and 140 Gbit/s total capacity.

Comment: There's nothing in the text quoted to say the "most powerful" claim is related to the propulsion system.

Comment: Hard to tell for this particular claim, but in general when talking about GEO satellite power, it refers to total RF power transmitted.

Comment: @CarlosN if you can put together a few examples of that, it could be posted as an answer (possibly including examples in comments above). The question has been around for close to a year now, so that might be helpful. Thanks!