# Any commercial communication satellite in GEO Orbit that supports 25 KW Power?

Tags: solar-power, communication-satellite, geostationary

As I understand, EchosTAR-11, built by Space systems Loral, was the first 20KW Commercial satellite.

(Reference: Recent Successful satellite systems- Visions for future by D.K.Sachdev).

Comment: possibly helpful (or not): [ViaSat's 18 kW solar array - largest ever for a commercial telecom satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21749/12102) and possibly  [What kind of power is referred to in “the…most powerful all-electric propulsion communications satellite ever produced”](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27548/12102)