# What prompted NASA to establish a KSC SWAT Team?

Tags: nasa, military, kennedy-space-center, security

Based on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48610/what-force-do-the-armed-guards-guarding-the-crew-1-crew-belong-to), it looks like KSC has not only its own police department (which is fairly common for large facilities, even things like universities) but also a SWAT team, which apparently was established in 1979.

What lead NASA to establish this? It long predates the post-9/11 concern with internal security. Was there some specific event? Or something that meant that some other organization (military? Other federal LEO?) would not provide heavily-armed security?

Comment: I don't know the answer. But somewhat related, I saw in a YouTube video that the Foreign Legion provides security for ESA launches from Kourou in French Guiana. The Foreign Legion is some serious business, so it's not just the Americans.

Comment: They certainly are -- how far back does that go? Of some note is that, well, French Guiana is not France.

Comment: I can't find the video (of course). But they've been there since 1973, according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kourou#CSG_and_the_French_Foreign_Legion_Arrive). Apparently spaceport duty is the boring part of their mission. Mostly they think about chasing illegal gold miners. https://www.popularmechanics.com/military/a7798/deep-in-the-jungle-with-the-french-foreign-legion-10487410/

Comment: Is this question just too young to bounty?

Comment: speaking of French Guyana: [How often are space launches substantially delayed by protests physically at the launch site?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20826/12102)

Answer (score -2):

Your answer is described here --> [here](https://www.nasa.gov/returntoflight/main/swat_feature.html)
Basically because a lot of important people are in the KSC and to stop any troublemakers

Comment: That doesn't really explain why they established or overall - all of those issues were true before 1979.

Comment: This is all I know and could find

Comment: Also the SWAT team is a part of the police department

Comment: @Leo suggest you spend some time reading answers on the site to see what is acceptable. You've written two poorly received answers in quick succession.